# GET query with headers via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to create crossdomain AJAX query, to receive the token, and display the received data, for example in the alert ()?

Part of the API:

Authorization

Properties of the method:
HTTP method : GET
URI: /

The input parameters (HTTP headers):
X-Auth-User - user login
X-Auth-Key - Key user is used (available in the Control Panel resources in the "My Profile")

Output parameters (HTTP headers):
X-Server-Management-Url - url to access the API functions
X-Auth-Token - token authentication

Return codes :
204 - no errors
401 - authorization error

Example:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.clodo.ru
X-Auth-User: jdoe
X-Auth-Key: a86850deb2742ec3cb41518e26aa2d89

Sample answer:
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2007 15:32:21 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Server-Management-Url: https://api.clodo.ru/v1
X-Auth-Token: eaaafd18-0fed-4b3a-81b4-663c99ec1cbb
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text / plain; charset = UTF- 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - headers and crossDomain options. Also [see here](http://easyxdm.net/wp/).

Comment: Sure 'cause it returns you html. Try another content-type.

Comment: Read the [api reference](http://lib.clodo.ru/clodo/clodo-api.html#section-1), please.

Comment: Also see status codes returned by server - for your sample it's 410. Resource gone.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand, how to modify my query to receive X-Server-Management-Url and X-Auth-Token?

Comment: These headers will be in the response to your query

Comment: I have this: [blocked] The page at https://panel.clodo.ru/ ran insecure content from http://api.clodo.ru/?callback=jQuery161007806437811814249_1384326827078&_=1384336258333.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41092/discussion-between-user2133984-and-lavrik)